# Android Exception NullPointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When I try to  call showQuestion() method from oncreate() function, null-pointer exception ocurrs, but if I try to call it through button it works, any suggestions. I want to call showQuestion() from onCreate() function so that when activity opens, it show one message.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt;

Button bt;
int i=0;
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jobj = null;
String line,results="";
static String json = "";
static JSONArray msgList = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new asynt().execute();

    txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    showQuestion(i);// null pointer exception
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i++;
            showQuestion(i);
        }
    });
}

 private void showQuestion(int i){
     try {
        JSONObject jsonobject = msgList.getJSONObject(i);
         String s = jsonobject.getString("messg");
        txt.setText(s);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
 }

 public class asynt extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>{

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void...vois) {
        JSONArray tha=null;;
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("questions.txt")));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            json=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }

            try {
                jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                tha = jobj.getJSONArray("message");

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tha;

    }
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        msgList = result;
    }
 }
}
```

Update:

```
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at      com.examp.ankurtesting.MainActivity.showQuestion(MainActivity.java:60)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.examp.ankurtesting.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:58)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.examp.ankurtesting.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4129)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17143)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
09-11 21:14:39.751: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Can uoi post logcat here?

Comment: Believe your jsonobject is null.

Comment: Where is your "CAT" means Logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure the variable msgList is what is throwing the NPE at

```
    JSONObject jsonobject = msgList.getJSONObject(i);
```

The reason why you're getting this error is because msgList is null until the AsyncTask is completed. The onCreate() method executes and finishes before the AsyncTask finishes. By the time you see and press the button which calls showQuestion(), the AsyncTask as completed and set the value of msgList, which is why you won't get an error when you press the button. Instead of calling this method in onCreate, call it in onPostExecute and add a onPreExecute to your AsyncTask to inform the user there is background work.

```
public class asynt extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>{

   ProgressDialog dialog;

   @Override
   public void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.show();
   }

   @Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void...vois) {
        ...
        return tha;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
       if(dialog.isShowing()) {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
       msgList = result;
       showQuestion(i);
   }
}
```

remove showQuestion(i) from the onCreate() method. The method onPostExecute of an AsyncTask is ran in the main UI thread.

As a side note, get into the habit of giving your variables better names. In eclipse presing Ctrl+Space does autocomplete so you can make names like LoadMessageListAsync instead of asynt, it makes code maintenance much nicer

Answer (score 0):

I can't find quesList in your example. If you mean msgList with it, I was thinking, that the result of the async task hasn't been written to msgList yet. You are calling showQuestion just very shortly after the task has been started. You are doing file io which is quite slow sometimes. Maybe, the JSONObject with index 0 is just null. Have you checked this already?

Comment: Its comment not answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think, that it is a good solution to wait until the task has finished as this makes the async task obsolete. So, there is no good solution to call showQuestion from onCreate, if the task is started in the same function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
private void showQuestion(int i){
     try {
        JSONObject jsonobject = quesList.getJSONObject(i);
         String s = jsonobject.getString("messg");
        txt.setText(s);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

have `quesList` where it is declare or initialized ????

Other points

may be your `quesList.getJSONObject(i);` returning **NULL**

so this **jsonobject.getString("messg");** will Throw **NullPointerException**

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your  `msgList` hasn't been initialized thus resulting in **NPE**.